# Google Sheet: Creating combination of all names from a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with following structure

| fname | lname | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nick | Fury | Manager |
| Tony | Stark | Manager |
| Bruce | Banner | Employee |
| Steve | Rogers | Employee |
| Clint | Barton | Employee |

I want to create another sheet with combinations of all complete names of employees
So, I would like the output to be

| names |
| --- |
| Bruce Banner - Steve Rogers |
| Bruce Banner - Clint Barton |
| Steve Rogers - Clint Barton |

I got the filter and concatenate part working with

`=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(Roster!C2:C&" " & Roster!D2:D, Roster!K2:K = "Employee"))`

But, I am not sure how to name create the combinations

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=index(split(query(unique(map(lambda(z,flatten(z& "" &transpose(z)))(filter(A:A&" "&B:B,C:C="Employee")),lambda(c,join("",sort(unique(transpose(split(c,"")))))))),"select Col1 where Col1 contains ''"),""))
```

[image]

Incase the [new functions](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/200022527?hl=en) are operational for you; here's another approach:

```
=let(a,filter(A:A&" "&B:B,C:C="Employee"),b,byrow(a,lambda(z,wraprows(z,counta(a),z))),query(map(tocol(b),tocol(b,,1),lambda(c,d,if(lt(c,d),{c,d},))),"where Col1<>''"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton. Worked like a charm. I really also liked the split delimiter is not a special character like -, that may already be in the name

Answer (score 0):

To get unique combinations without using `split()`, use `reduce()`:

```
=let( 
  names, filter(A2:A & " " & B2:B, C2:C = "Employee"), 
  reduce( 
    { "name 1", "name 2" }, names,
    lambda( 
      result, name, 
      reduce( 
        result, filter(names, names <> name), 
        lambda( 
          result, otherName, 
          if( 
            name < otherName, 
            { 
              result; 
              { name, otherName } 
            }, 
            result 
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Text string manipulation and `split()` can mistreat dates, Booleans and numbers in certain formats, together with text strings that look like those types. That won't matter with names like `Bruce Banner` but `split()` will coerce text strings like `1 2`, `1 2 3` and `1111-2-3` to dates, while the formula above will faithfully reproduce the original values.